# Append to zip() in Python

Tags: python, append

Given any number of zipped lists, e.g.

```
>>> L1 = [1,2,3]
>>> L2 = [1,2,3]
>>> zipped = zip(L1, L2)
[[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

how can I append another list to zipped that produces the same output as

```
>>> L3 = [5,5,5]
>>> zip(L1, L2, L3)
[(1, 1, 5), (2, 2, 5), (3, 3, 5)]
```

I was thinking in the direction of append(), but that produces the following undesired result

```
>>> zipped.append(L3)
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), [5, 5, 5]]
```

Background: I want to create the zipped-list within a loop for any number of lists.

EDIT:

It appears to me now that I was missing one part of my problem. Here is a MWE based an Ryan's answer:

```
import random

N = 4
zipped2 = zip([1,2,3],[1,2,3])  # works
zipped2 = []  # does not work
for n in range(N):
    Ln = random.sample(xrange(100),3)
    zipped2 = [old + (new,) for old, new in zip(zipped2, Ln)]

print(zipped2)
```

Using this method on pre-zipped lists works perfectly. However, I would like to create the entire output inside the loop and thus would like to start with an empty list.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your edit. If you just want to zip any number of lists together, it’s `zip(*lists)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really like the word `zip`, you can use it lots:

```
zip(*zip(*zipped), L3)
```

If you’re using Python 2 or are a fan of having people understand your code, a list comprehension is probably best:

```
[old + (new,) for old, new in zip(zipped, L3)]
```

Your edit seems to indicate you just want to zip some number of lists, though:

```
import random

N = 4
columns = []
for n in xrange(N):
    Ln = random.sample(xrange(100), 3)
    columns.append(Ln)

zipped2 = zip(*columns)
print(zipped2)
```

Comment: Worth +10 for *are a fan of having people understand your code*

Answer (score 7):

You can create the lists you want to "append" before-hand and then unpack them with `*`:

```
lists = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

print(list(zip([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], *lists)))
# [(1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3)]
```

`lists` can contain an arbitrary number of sublists.

Answer (score 1):

For python3:

```
lst1 = [1,2,3]
lst2 = ['a','b','c']
lst3 = ['*','#','+']
lst4 = [4,5,6]

zipped = zip(lst1,lst2,lst3) #any number of lists
newlist = [(*z, j) for z, j in zip(zipped, lst4)]

#output
(1, 'a', '*', 4)
(2, 'b', '#', 5)
(3, 'c', '+', 6)
```

Works with any number of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
[(i[0], i[1], j) for i, j in zip(zipped, L3)]
```